# Was ist der Terminus für die undeklinierte Form eines Adjektivs?

Tags: grammar-identification

Ich suche den Begriff für die undeklinierte Grundform eines Adjektivs, quasi das, was der Infinitiv bei Verben ist. Also z.B. "grün", "laut", "schnell".

Wikipedia schweigt sich in allen Grammatikartikeln hierüber aus.

Wenn man nach "Adjektiv" und "Grundform" googled, findet man ausschließlich den Begriff "Positiv" - das ist aber die Grundform in Bezug auf Steigerung. "Die schnelle Frau" benutzt den Positiv (im Gegensatz zu "Die schnellere Frau"), das Adjektiv ist aber dekliniert.

Es ist auch nicht "Nominativ" - das ist ja auch schon (teil-)dekliniert.

Eventuell gibt es einen solchen Begriff allgemein auch für andere Nomen? Ich kenne auch keinen entsprechenden Begriff für Substantive.

Comment: "für andere Nomen"      
Du zählst Adjektive zu den Nomen?

Comment: Die Grundform lautet *Grundform*. Ein anderer Begriff ist mir bei Adjektiven (bewusst) noch nicht begegnet.

Comment: @ErithreusHoffing Ich hab meine Grammatik zum größten Teil im lateinischen Umfeld gelernt, da sind Nomen (u.A.) Substantive und Adjektive - quasi die deklinierbaren. Diese Definition ist auch im Deutschen durchaus üblich. Nomen als Synonym für Substantiv ist die andere übliche Variante, die wohl auch durchs Englische vermehrt Verbreitung findet inzwischen.

Comment: Substantiv und Nomen zusammenzuzählen ist enorm unpraktisch, allem voran bei der Regel, was groß geschrieben werden muss.... Denn alle Substantive groß geschrieben werden, sind damit nicht Adjektive und Pronomen mitgemeint...

Answer (score 1):

Du sagtest ja bereits "Grundform"... :) Siehe auch "Grundform (Grammatik)" in der Wikipedia.

Der Vergleich zum Infinitiv des Verbs hinkt außerdem, der Infinitiv *-en* ist auch eine Endung des Verbs. Wenn man das als Grundform bezeichnet, dann weil man eigentlich "Zitierform" meint. Der Kontrast finit-infinit ist eine Spezialität von Verben, ein Vergleich zu den Formen von Adjektiven drängt sich m.E. nicht auf.

Comment: Die Erklärung, warum der Kontrast *finit – infinit* eine Spezialität von Verben ist und dass die Übertragung auf Adjektive nicht sinnvoll ist, gefällt mir. (+1)

Comment: Es mag sein, dass der Vergleich hinkt. Aber in beiden Fällen geht es halt um die Form, die man nutzt, um über das Wort zu reden, um es als Vokabel zu lernen. Es fällt mir schwer, zu glauben, dass es dafür keinen lateinischen Begriff gibt. Ich glaube, das wäre so ziemlich das einzige grammatikalische Konzept ohne lateinischen Namen...

Comment: @kratenko: Zitierform.